Returning a pointer on the heap and the consequential behaviour
Imagine I have the below scenario: Now if I allocate a pointer inside a function on the heap, and return this pointer back to the main program, is the memory still on the heap, and do I have to free it?
static char* assignValue()
{
  char* value = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1024);
  strcpy(value, "random");

  return value;
}

int main(void)
{
  char* mainValue = assignValue(); // is the memory still on the heap?

  printf("%s", mainValue);

  free(mainValue);  // and, is this also correct?
}

I was wondering how to handle this situation.

Since you tagged this c++, the answer is that you should avoid this situation by using make_unique (or make_shared), and stay away from malloc or new.

Yes, every call to malloc must be matched by a call to free. That's why we don't use malloc in C++ for pretty much anything. Or "raw pointers" in general. Very inconvenient and error-prone stuff, those beasties.

C and C++ are different languages and the answer would be different. Please don't tag both unless you ask about some specific difference between them.

please tag only the language you are actually using.

Don't use the heap tag for this. Updated.

you seem to confuse the pointer and the pointee. Copying a pointer does not change anything about the memory it points to

Sorry I updated it. I was wondering what the correct approach in C would be.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai So this would also mean, that I can safely free the content with the second pointer?

Does your code has #include <stdlib.h> and stdio and string?

@ArthurShelby yes, free(mainValue); is correct (it is actually required, to avoid a memory leak).

@wohlstad Nice, I was wondering, how to free it because the original pointer wouldnt be accessible anymore and I didnt know if freeing it with mainValue would be undefined behaviour. This cleared my question!

@KamilCuk Should be, why are you asking?

why are you asking? Because without #include <stdlib.h> your code is invalid.

void *a = malloc(10); void *b = a; free(b); is perfectly fine. It's the pointer value from malloc that needs to be freed. As long as the pointer value (when converted to void *) being freed compares equal to the pointer value returned by malloc, then all is well. After it is freed, then all copies of the pointer value become invalid.

@KamilCuk Well, good to know, but this wasnt my question. I was wondering if I should free the heap memory with the second pointer in the main function.

Also sizeof(char*) * 1024 allocates memory for 1024 pointers of char. To allocate 1024 cahracters, use sizeof(char) * 1024

The rule of thumb is that the code responsible for allocation is also responsible for deallocation. So if you write a function returning a pointer to dynamic memory, you should also provide a function for cleaning up that memory.

In sort :
Yes.
In long :
char* value = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1024);

malloc() return a pointer to a memory location.
And you store this memory location in value for later usage.
value is a stack variable where you stock this memory location, and have the same behavior of any stack variable. (in this case value gonna be destroy at the end of the scope)
The malloc() memory location is in the heap and don't have the stack behavior.
But you need to pass this memory location to free().
If you don't pass this memory location to free(), that create a still reachable leak.
If you loss this pointer to memory location somewhere this create a definitely lost or indirectly lost leak.
char* mainValue = assignValue();

Here you create a new mainValue and you assign this lvalue (left value) with the assignValue() fonction.
In assignValue() you return the value containing the value malloc() give you (the heap memory location).
That have for effect to store the value of value in mainValue.
We can check that with printf("%p") (%p is for pointer argument) :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *
foo(void)
{
        char * ptr;

        ptr = malloc(1);
        printf("%p\n", ptr);
        return (ptr);
}

int
main(void)
{
        char * my_ptr;

        my_ptr = foo();
        printf("%p\n", my_ptr);
        free(my_ptr);
        return (0);
}

Output :
➜  test ./a.out
0x557cb28e92a0
0x557cb28e92a0

Here we can see two time the same value. (0x is for hexadecimal value)
And with that I can safely pass the my_ptr pointer to free().
You need to be careful with heap memory location pointer.
If you give a wrong pointer to free(), that a undefined behavior.
And create leak is also not a option.
You need to be sure you free() everything correctly.
If you start to do bigger code where error is common, you probably want to use a debugger.

Richard Stallman’s advice, from personal experience, is to turn to the
debugger as soon as you can reproduce the problem. Don’t try to avoid
it by using other methods instead— occasionally they are shortcuts,
but usually they waste an unbounded amount of time. With the debugger,
you will surely find the bug in a reasonable time; overall, you will
get your work done faster. The sooner you get serious and start the
debugger, the sooner you are likely to find the bug.

for more info, check the man

For starters it is unclear why there is allocated memory using the size of pointer of the type char *.
char* value = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1024);
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

It seems it is a typo and instead you mean
char* value = (char*)malloc(sizeof( char ) * 1024);

or just
char* value = (char*)malloc(1024);

because sizeof( char ) is always equal to 1.
As for your question then according to the C23 Standard (7.24.3 Memory management functions)

The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the allocation until
the deallocation

So the allocated extent of memory will be kept after exiting the function assignValue. And as the function returns a pointer to the allocated extent of memory you can use it to access the memory and consequently to free it
free(mainValue);

So the lifetine of the allocated array extends from this allocation within the function
char* value = (char*)malloc(1024);

and till its dealloction in main
free(mainValue);

Even if the allocation will not be successfull nevertheless you may call for a returned null pointer the function free
free(mainValue);

Of course you should check whether the returned pointer by the standard  function malloc and by your function assignValue is not a null pointer if you are going to access the allocated memory as for example in this statement
strcpy(value, "random");

as for example
static char * assignValue()
{
    char *value = malloc( 1024 );

   
    if ( value ) strcpy(value, "random");

    return value;
}

